# Turn JS Object into FormData before submitting the data in Server with React

Tags: reactjs

So let's say we do have this object that has an array on it, also includes some files and other types.

```js
const state = {
  "name": "Coffe",
  "description": "..."
  "visibilty": true,
  "tags": ["Chill", "Not Healthy"],
  "photos": [File, File] // those are File objects from upload
}
```

So because we are sending images we need to convert all the fields into form data when we send it on the server and I don't know something that works also with the complexity of the object when it also includes an array.

Comment: Have you tried something with iteration?

Comment: But you can't iterate a form data by default without a special method right?